# Why does Gradle downgrade my transitive dependencies in a Grails 3.1 application?

Tags: grails, gradle, grails-3.1

I am having a problem with a transitive dependency of my `grails-flyway` plugin. `org.grails.plugins:grails-flyway:0.2.1` declares a dependency to `org.flywaydb:flyway-core:4.0.1`. When I include the plugin into my Grails 3.1.6 project Gradle downgrades Flyway to version 3.2.1.

```
+--- org.grails.plugins:grails-flyway:0.2.1
|    \--- org.flywaydb:flyway-core:4.0.1 -> 3.2.1
```

My Gradle build file looks like this

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        grailsVersion = project.grailsVersion
    }
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
        classpath "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:${assetPipelinePluginVersion}"
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5:5.0.5"
        classpath 'com.github.ben-manes:gradle-versions-plugin:0.12.0'
    }
}

version "0.40.15"
group "zsc.supporter"

apply plugin: "war"
apply plugin: "org.grails.grails-web"
apply plugin: "org.grails.grails-gsp"
apply plugin: "org.grails.grails-doc"
apply plugin: "asset-pipeline"
apply plugin: 'com.github.ben-manes.versions'

ext {
    grailsVersion = project.grailsVersion
    gradleWrapperVersion = project.gradleWrapperVersion
}

repositories {
    maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/saw303/plugins" }
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.grails:grails-bom:$grailsVersion"
    }
    applyMavenExclusions false
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    compile "org.grails:grails-core"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    compile "org.grails:grails-dependencies"
    compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate4"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache"
    console "org.grails:grails-console"
    profile "org.grails.profiles:web:3.1.6"
    runtime "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-grails:${assetPipelinePluginVersion}"
    runtime "com.h2database:h2"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing"
    testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb"
    testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.52.0"
    testRuntime "net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.21"

    compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.0.4"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:quartz:2.0.8"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:mail:2.0.0.RC4"
    compile "eu.bitwalker:UserAgentUtils:1.18"
    compile 'org.mnode.ical4j:ical4j:1.0.7'
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:browser-detection:3.1.0'
    compile "com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:7.3.1"
    runtime 'org.grails.plugins:grails-flyway:0.2.1'

    testCompile "org.grails.plugins:grails-wizer:0.3"
    testCompile 'org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support:5.0.5.RELEASE'

    runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.29'
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = gradleWrapperVersion
}

assets {
    minifyJs = true
    minifyCss = true
}
```

Currently I do not understand why Gradle downgrades my transitive dependency. Can someone provide on this?

I am aware that I can force the `flyway-core:4.0.1` dependency in my `build.gradle` but I would like to understand what the downgrade causes.

**UPDATE-1**

When I run `gradle dependencies | grep flyway` I get the following output.

```
+--- org.grails.plugins:grails-flyway:0.2.1
|    \--- org.flywaydb:flyway-core:4.0.1 -> 3.2.1
+--- org.grails.plugins:grails-flyway:0.2.1
|    \--- org.flywaydb:flyway-core:4.0.1 -> 3.2.1
+--- org.grails.plugins:grails-flyway:0.2.1
|    \--- org.flywaydb:flyway-core:4.0.1 -> 3.2.1
+--- org.grails.plugins:grails-flyway:0.2.1
|    \--- org.flywaydb:flyway-core:4.0.1 -> 3.2.1
```

Please find the complete output at [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/MtKVu83y). The `grails-flyway` plugin and its pom.xml can be found at [Bintray](https://bintray.com/saw303/plugins/grails-flyway/0.2.1/view#files/org/grails/plugins/grails-flyway/0.2.1).

**UPDATE-2**

I tried to force Gradle to use `org.flywaydb:flyway-core:4.0.1` according to [Gradles Reference](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html).

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core:4.0.1'
}
```

That does not affect the problem. The dependency tree still uses version 3.2.1 of `flyway-core`.

```
+--- org.grails.plugins:grails-flyway:0.2.1
|    \--- org.flywaydb:flyway-core:4.0.1 -> 3.2.1
```

**UPDATE-3**

Gradles `dependencyInsight` command

```
gradle dependencyInsight --dependency flyway-core --configuration runtime
```

results in

```
:dependencyInsight
org.flywaydb:flyway-core:3.2.1 (selected by rule)

org.flywaydb:flyway-core:4.0.1 -> 3.2.1
\--- org.grails.plugins:grails-flyway:0.2.1
     \--- runtime
```

What means `(selected by rule)`?

**"Solution" - or how to work it around**

I was not able to find the rule that causes Gradle to use `flyway-core:3.2.1` instead of `flyway-core:4.0.1`. But I found a way to work around the problem.

I added the following to my `build.gradle` to modify my Gradle `runtime` resolution strategy.

```
configurations.runtime.resolutionStrategy {

    eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails det ->

        if (det.requested.name == 'flyway-core' && det.requested.group == 'org.flywaydb') {
            det.useVersion(det.requested.version)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any other dependency, which is dependent on `org.flywaydb:flyway-core:3.2.1`? Just as suppose, that there is some lib, with dependency on older version and Gradle just solves this by downgrading the plugin's version, because it seems to be most evident way

Comment: I cannot find any other flyway-core version with the dependency tree. :(

Comment: You can try to inverse your search by running
`./gradlew dependencyInsight --dependency flyway-core`. Then you should be able to see who requieres flyway-core. Maybe that gives you a hint

Comment: You can use this solution: https://github.com/spring-gradle-plugins/dependency-management-plugin/issues/165#issuecomment-295651715

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The thing causing it is the `spring-boot-dependencies-1.3.3.RELEASE.pom`

This forcing the flyway version to 3.2.1

According to the [Spring Boot docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-customize-dependency-versions) you should be able to add a line like this to your `build.gradle`:

`ext['flyway.version'] = '4.0.1'`

Comment: how do you find out what dependency has such transitive dependency with lower version? I have similar problem, but cennot find out where does it come from, so I cannot determine what `ext[...]` should i overwrite

Comment: the problem is, how do you find **it is the`spring-boot-dependencies-1.3.3.RELEASE.pom`**

Answer (score 27):

Goto your Gradle cache files folder:

```
cd ~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1
```

search this version number:

```
grep -r "3.2.1" *
```

you will find out which pom file is using this version,
usually it's something in `spring-boot-dependencies-x.y.z.RELEASE.pom` :

```
<flyway.version>3.2.1</flyway.version>
......
<groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
    <version>${flyway.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

which means, if you use `spring-boot`, it will overwrite some dependency version.

you can overwrite it again, by adding the following line in your `gradle.properties` file:

```
flyway.version=4.0.1
```

I encounter a similar problem and wasted several hours on it.
So I left this information here, hope this could save your time if you get stuck into this problem

Comment: Good catch. Here's my slightly more efficient command, assuming you know you're looking for 'pom' files: `find -name "*pom" -type f -exec grep -Hn '3.0.4.RELEASE' '{}' +`