# Gradle Not Honoring Forced Dependency Version

Tags: java, spring, gradle, dependency-management, spring-hateoas

I am unable to force a version of a dependency using Gradle. My goal is to use version `0.20.0.RELEASE` of the Spring HATEOAS library, but despite all my efforts it keeps resolving to `0.19.0.RELEASE`.

I have attempted a number of strategies, both in isolation and in combination with one another. These strategies include, but are possibly not limited to, the following (note that in all cases `$springHateoasVersion`is defined in the `gradle.properties` file that resides in the directory that is the parent of the directory for the module declaring the Spring HATEOAS dependency):

#1 (in the `build.gradle` file for the module that declares the dependency)

```
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

dependencyManagement {
    dependencies {
        dependency group:'org.springframework.hateoas', name:'spring-hateoas', version:"$springHateoasVersion"
    }
}
```

#2  (in the `build.gradle` file for the module that declares the dependency)

```
compile ("org.springframework.hateoas:spring-hateoas:$springHateoasVersion") { force = true }
```

#3 (in the `build.gradle` file of the **parent** directory)

```
subprojects {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force "org.springframework.hateoas:spring-hateoas:$springHateoasVersion"
        }
    }
}
```

I have done my best to research this problem:

This question has an accepted answer, but doesn't seem like an exact match for the problem that I'm experiencing: [How can I force Gradle to set the same version for two dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28444016/how-can-i-force-gradle-to-set-the-same-version-for-two-dependencies)

Neither of these questions seem to have accepted answers: 1) [Gradle is not honoring resolutionStrategy.force](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19282893/gradle-is-not-honoring-resolutionstrategy-force), 2) [Forcing a module version has no effect on generated org.eclipse.wst.common.component](https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2496).

In addition to the fact that my project is broken (because I'm using the wrong version of Spring HATEOAS), I can explicitly see that Gradle is "consciously" selecting the incorrect dependency version despite all my protestations. When I run `./gradlew dependencyInsight --dependency spring-hateoas`, I see the following output:

```
org.springframework.hateoas:spring-hateoas:0.19.0.RELEASE (selected by rule)

org.springframework.hateoas:spring-hateoas:0.20.0.RELEASE -> 0.19.0.RELEASE
\--- project :Commons
     \--- compile
```

Despite the name, the `dependencyInsight` task provides surprisingly little insight into *which* rule caused Gradle to select the inappropriate dependency version, let alone how I might go about circumventing said rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37166293/858003). Of course this was the one thing I didn't try because it "didn't seem material". :-/

In order to get things working, I added the following to the `build.gradle` file of the **parent** directory (relative to the directory for the module that declared the dependency on Spring HATEOAS).

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

    dependencyManagement {
        applyMavenExclusions false
    }

    ext['spring-hateoas.version'] = "$springHateoasVersion"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

honored by e.g.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        exclusiveContent {
            filter {
                includeGroup "com.facebook.react"
            }
            forRepository {
                maven {
                    url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

ref to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35204#issuecomment-1304740228