# Gradle - understand where a dependency comes from

Tags: java, gradle

I have a project that depends transitively on `hibernate-core` versions 5.2.x and 5.3.x.
I would like to know where does 5.2.x comes from.
Using the `dependencies` task I can only see libraries depend on 5.3.x.

Using dependencyInsight:

```
$ ./gradlew -q :mymodule:dependencyInsight --dependency hibernate-core --configuration compile
org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.2.10.Final (selected by rule)
   variant "runtime"

org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.3.7.Final -> 5.2.10.Final
   variant "runtime"
\--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.1.0.RELEASE
     +--- project :core
     |    \--- compile
     \--- com.github.alturkovic.distributed-lock:distributed-lock- 
jdbc:1.2.2
          \--- project :core (*)
```

But both packages listed here depend on 5.3, not 5.2.

So how can I know where this version comes from?

EDIT: both modules `dependencyInsight`, without `--configuration`:

```
$ ./gradlew -q :moduleA:dependencyInsight --dependency hibernate-core                        
org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.3.7.Final (selected by rule)
   variant "default+runtime" [
      Requested attributes not found in the selected variant:
         org.gradle.usage                   = java-api
         org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type = jvm
   ]
+--- compileClasspath
\--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.1.0.RELEASE
     +--- project :core
     |    \--- compileClasspath
     \--- com.github.alturkovic.distributed-lock:distributed-lock-jdbc:1.2.2
          \--- project :core (*)

(*) - dependencies omitted (listed previously)

A web-based, searchable dependency report is available by adding the --scan option.
$ ./gradlew -q :moduleB:dependencyInsight --dependency hibernate-core 
org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.3.7.Final
   variant "runtime" [
      Requested attributes not found in the selected variant:
         org.gradle.usage                   = java-api
         org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type = jvm
   ]
\--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.1.0.RELEASE
     +--- compileClasspath
     \--- com.github.alturkovic.distributed-lock:distributed-lock-jdbc:1.2.2
          \--- compileClasspath

(*) - dependencies omitted (listed previously)

A web-based, searchable dependency report is available by adding the --scan option.
```

Comment: basically 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.2.10.Final (selected by rule)' tells gradle somehow to ignore your listed dependency and force to 5.2.10.Final.
Can you try to list the dependencies without the compile configuration? So the runtime and compile will be listed?
It might be that this rule was added by a spring module like ' Spring dependency-management-plugin'
Might be an helpfull answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37153484/why-does-gradle-downgrade-my-transitive-dependencies-in-a-grails-3-1-application

Comment: Hard to tell without your `build.gradle` file, though I'm guessing something with build variants judging by the first line of the output

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using gradle to find dependency tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21645071/using-gradle-to-find-dependency-tree)

Comment: @prophet1906 using dependencies task was the first thing I tried :D

Comment: @JeroenSteenbeeke not using build variants (aren't those just an Android thing?)

Comment: did you try project reports plugin? check build/reports/project/dependencies/index.html

Comment: @andrew not sure if they're Android specific (I do primarily use Gradle with Android), but the build output mentions variants by name

Comment: @prophet1906 tried project-report, still only shows org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.3.7.Final ➡ 5.2.10.Final but never list a dependency depending on 5.2 explicitly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kind of embarrassing.

In our `gradle.properties` we had:

```
hibernate.version=5.2.10.Final
```

and I wasn't aware of it. I discovered it randomly today.