# Why is Gradle resolving an older version of a dependency?

Tags: gradle

I'm trying to debug why Gradle is picking up `r2dbc-spi:0.8.6.RELEASE` when it is not brought transitively by any dependency. The output of `./gradlew :proj:dependencyInsight --dependency r2dbc-spi --configuration runtimeClasspath` is the folowing:

```
io.r2dbc:r2dbc-spi:0.8.6.RELEASE (selected by rule)
   variant "runtime" [
      org.gradle.status                  = release (not requested)
      org.gradle.usage                   = java-runtime
      org.gradle.libraryelements         = jar
      org.gradle.category                = library

      Requested attributes not found in the selected variant:
         org.gradle.dependency.bundling     = external
         org.gradle.jvm.environment         = standard-jvm
         org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type = jvm
         org.gradle.jvm.version             = 17
   ]

io.r2dbc:r2dbc-spi:0.9.0.RELEASE -> 0.8.6.RELEASE
+--- project :proj-data
|    \--- runtimeClasspath
\--- org.postgresql:r2dbc-postgresql:0.9.0.RELEASE
     \--- project :proj-data (*)

(*) - dependencies omitted (listed previously)
```

It's clear that `0.8.6.RELEASE` is picked up, but what I don't understand is why? Or where does it come from? I thought the following snippet:

```
io.r2dbc:r2dbc-spi:0.9.0.RELEASE -> 0.8.6.RELEASE
+--- project :proj-data
|    \--- runtimeClasspath
\--- org.postgresql:r2dbc-postgresql:0.9.0.RELEASE
     \--- project :proj-data (*)
```

Indicated which versions of the dependency are available (in this case, as transitive dependencies). However, `0.8.6.RELEASE` does not appear anywhere to the left of the arrow, so doesn't this mean that it's not provided by any dependency?

**UPDATE**
Decided to try and force it with no result, I added this snippet to the parent project's `build.gradle`:

```kotlin
subprojects {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force("io.r2dbc:r2dbc-spi:0.9.0.RELEASE")
        }
    }
}
```

The result is almost exactly the same, only that `dependencyInsight` seems to think `0.8.6.RELEASE` was chosen by force:

```
io.r2dbc:r2dbc-spi:0.8.6.RELEASE
   variant "runtime" [
      org.gradle.status                  = release (not requested)
      org.gradle.usage                   = java-runtime
      org.gradle.libraryelements         = jar
      org.gradle.category                = library

      Requested attributes not found in the selected variant:
         org.gradle.dependency.bundling     = external
         org.gradle.jvm.environment         = standard-jvm
         org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type = jvm
         org.gradle.jvm.version             = 17
   ]
   Selection reasons:
      - Forced
      - Selected by rule

io.r2dbc:r2dbc-spi:0.9.0.RELEASE -> 0.8.6.RELEASE
+--- project :proj-data
|    \--- runtimeClasspath
\--- org.postgresql:r2dbc-postgresql:0.9.0.RELEASE
     \--- project :proj-data (*)

(*) - dependencies omitted (listed previously)
```

Comment: Can you share what your `dependencies` block looks like?

Comment: Sorry, I already found out this question is a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37153484/why-does-gradle-downgrade-my-transitive-dependencies-in-a-grails-3-1-application) and flagged it