# Gradle dependency for mssql-jdbc downgrades version even with strictly enabled

Tags: java, gradle, mssql-jdbc

I've got a build.gradle (gradle version 8.6) that has

```
compileJava {
        targetCompatibility = '21'
        sourceCompatibility = '21'
}
dependencies {
  implementation "com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:12.6.1.jre11"
}
```

Running "gradle dependencies" shows a downgrade to '10.2.3.jre8':

```
+--- com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:12.6.1.jre11 -> 10.2.3.jre8
```

There are no other dependencies which include mssql-jdbc.

If I enable strict version it does the same thing:

```
implementation("com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc") {
        version {
            strictly "$sqlServerConnectorVersion"
        }
}
```

Result is the same downgrade.

```
+--- com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:{strictly 12.6.1.jre11} -> 10.2.3.jre8
```

What am I missing here?

SOLUTION
The solution to the problem is very specific to our project so I can't go into the details, but it involved gradle downgrading the version to 10.2.3.jre8 in a different sub-project which didn't need mssql-jdbc in the first place so we just excluded it.

ROOT CAUSE

This post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37153484/why-does-gradle-downgrade-my-transitive-dependencies-in-a-grails-3-1-application) seems to be the root cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be happening because of some other dependency needing a lower version of the mssql-jdbc. Try running this command to get more info:

```
gradle dependencyInsight --dependency mssql-jdbc
```